# Mercurial: move MQ patch to shelve?

Tags: mercurial, shelving

Emacs VC mode show changes in directory state but ignore MQ changes...

I want to remove patch from queue and apply it on working directory.

This is possible with usual `patch` command, but it require passing some arguments and paths to utilities (which is inconvenient as not all environment allow autocompletion).

I expect `hg` built-in solution. Ideally - to move patch to shelve.

Comment: Do you want to move things from the patch to the working folder? Or from the patch to the shelf? Its not clear./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving changes from MQ to working tree and forgetting it:

```
$ hg qgoto my.patch
$ hg qpop
$ hg qdel --keep my.patch
$ patch -p1 .hg/patches/my.patch
$ rm .hg/patches/my.patch
```

In Emacs to see difference in top MQ patches I find command `C-u C-x v D qparent RET qtip RET` which is:

```
$ hg diff -r qparent:qtip
```

or shorter:

```
$ hg diff -r qparent
```

or:

```
$ hg qdiff
```

but latest command doesn't present in Emacs VC mode.